In oracle SQL developer, how do I automatically generate a relational diagram which is 2 "levels" deep
this is the "model" tab I click to generate a relational diagram
However, this function only generates the the immediate relations (table A to B). Is there a way to generate relations by 1 more level? (table A to B, B to C)
Using Oracle DB19, and sql developer version 23.1.1.345, Build 345.2114

In this example (based on Scott's sample emp and dept tables), I

created primary key on dept.deptno
foreign key on emp.deptno pointing to dept.deptno

all that represents what you call "one level"


created additional table named locations with loc column as its primary key
created foreign key on dept.loc pointing to locations.loc

that represents the "second level"



Shortly, that's emp --> dept --> locations.
Now, in SQL Developer, this is what I get when I select various tables:

Apparently, "two levels" are visible when you select the "middle" table in that chain (which is dept in my example).
Therefore, try to do the same.

you have much more control if you create an actual data modeler design, and import the entire data dictionary...you can hit the modeler button on the toolbar in your screenshot to take those objects and use them to create a new design as a a quick-start

Thanks all for the suggestions!
Took advice to import the entire data dictionary, and selected neighbours around tables I want to look at
Right click on a table in the relational model > select neighbours > create subview from selected tables

this article provided the answer i was looking for:
https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/04/wont-you-be-my-neighbor-selecting-related-objects-in-oracle-sql-developer-data-modeler/

